# Upload file with dynamic destination using nestjs and multer

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, multer

I am trying to upload file using nestjs and multer. I have to create dynamic destination for file by calling a service.

I tried to implement NestInterceptor referring to this link https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/1239. But i am not able to get request body inside the interceptor. From the frontend , I am passing formData with some extra keys required to create file path. But request body in empty.

My custom interceptor implementation

```
@Injectable()
export class CustomFilesInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
constructor(private readonly service: Service) {}


async intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler) {

const ctx = context.switchToHttp();

// Request Body is Empty
const {body} = ctx.getRequest()


// Call Service here
const path = this.service.getPath();

const fileIntConst = fileInterceptor('upfile', {
  storage: multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function(req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, `./files`);
    },
    filename: function(req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, `${file.originalName}`);
    },
  }),
});

const fileInt = new fileIntConst();

return fileInt.intercept(context, next);
}
}
```